# Using a hashtable key in a property

Tags: powershell, hashtable, office365, csom

I am trying to adapt the script found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/116360/1806) to a PowerShell CSOM equivalent.

> ```
> function setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldName,properties,success,failure)
> {
>      var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
>      var web = ctx.get_web(); 
>      var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
>      var field = list.get_fields().getByTitle(fieldName);
>      field.setShowInDisplayForm(properties.ShowInDisplayForm);
>      field.setShowInNewForm(properties.ShowInNewForm);
>      field.setShowInEditForm(properties.ShowInEditForm);
>      field.set_hidden(properties.Hidden);
>      field.update();
>      ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,failure);
> }
> ```

In the process of generalizing it, I am trying to pass in a hashtable. I would like to iterate over this hashtable to dynamically build the properties to edit, but I'm having a little trouble. My function and usage looks like this:

```
Function Set-FieldProperties{

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ListTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FieldName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][hashtable]$Properties
    )
    begin {
        $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url) 
        $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
    }
    process{

        $web = $context.Web
        $list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
        $field = $list.Fields.GetByTitle($FieldName)
        foreach($key in $Properties.Keys){
            $key
            $Properties[$key]
            #failing to make this part dynamic
            $field.$key($Properties[$key])

        }
        <#$field.ShowInDisplayForm($properties.ShowInDisplayForm)
        $field.ShowInNewForm($properties.ShowInNewForm)
        $field.ShowInEditForm($properties.ShowInEditForm)
        $field.Hidden($properties.Hidden)
        try{
            $field.update()
            $context.executeQuery()
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Field properties updated successfully"
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
        }
        #>
    }
    end{
     $context.Dispose()
    }

}
Set-FieldPoperties -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -ListTitle "CalcColumns" -FieldName "Title" -Properties @{"SetShowInDisplayForm"=$true; "SetShowInEditForm"=$false}
```

My struggle is in how to make this portion build up the desired output:

```
 foreach($key in $Properties.Keys){
                $key
                $Properties[$key]
                #failing to make this part dynamic
                $field.$key($Properties[$key])

            }
```

How do you use the key as a property to set on the $field object in this case? Is that possible? I don't want to have some huge if block checking for all the possible properties, I'd like it to build those based on what the user passes in the $Properties hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Expression` to create a dynamic command, but we need to escape some variables so they are not expanded before execution.

The problem with @avvi's solution is that `$Properties[$key]` will return `$true`, but since it's a subexpression in a string, it will be converted to `True`. When this is executed it will be an unquoted string which makes it a call for a function/cmdlet/program-name. This will throw an error because a method named `True` doesn't exist etc. Ex.

```
"`$field.$key($($Properties[$key]))"
#Returns:
$field.test(True)

#ERROR!!
At line:17 char:13
+ $field.test(True)
+             ~


"`$field.$key(`$Properties[`$key])"
#Returns:
$field.test($Properties[$key])

#Good. Will get value from Properties on execution => Object will not be converted to string.
#This allow both $key and returned value from $Properties to be any type of object
```

Try:

```
## START Sample data
$field = New-Object psobject
Add-Member -InputObject $field -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "test" -Value { param($in) $in.Gettype() | Out-Host; "in = $in" }

$Properties = @{ "test"  = $true }
## END Sample data


foreach($key in $Properties.Keys){
    $key
    $Properties[$key]
    #failing to make this part dynamic
    Invoke-Expression "`$field.$key(`$Properties[`$key])"
}
```

Output:

```
#From $key and $Properties[$key]
test
True

#From invoke-expression result
IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType        
-------- -------- ----    --------        
True     True     Boolean System.ValueType                                                                                

in = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Invoke-Expression
```

This will dynamically evaluate a string.

So it will look like this:

```
iex "`$field.$key($($Properties[$key]))"
```

- the double quotes allow evaluation of enclosed variables
- the backtick escapes the $field parameter so that it's outputted literally
- $key is evaluated as the value of $key
- the $() will make the enclosed expression evaluate

Comment: This is really close, except the booleans aren't coming over as $true or $false as I think I need for the function to execute. What or how would I need to adapt for that to be the case?